# Ruby multiple background threads

Tags: ruby

I need to run multiple background threads in a thread pool with timeout.
The scheme is something like:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'thread'

def foo(&block)
  bar(block)
end

def bar(block)
  Thread.abort_on_exception=true
  @main = Thread.new { block.call }
end


foo {
sleep 1
puts 'test'
}
```

Why if i run that i get no output? (and no sleep wait?)

Answer (score 3):

The program ends when the main thread ends. You have to wait on the thread created by `bar` using `join`:

```
foo {
  sleep 1
  puts 'test'
}.join
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the work_queue gem http://rubygems.org/gems/work_queue/