# what is the point of .join in Ruby threads?

Tags: ruby, concurrency

Lets take this code from this question:

[Ruby multiple background threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865601/ruby-multiple-background-threads)

and add a line:

```
require 'thread'

def foo(&block)
  bar(block)
end

def bar(block)
  Thread.abort_on_exception=true
  @main = Thread.new { block.call }
end


foo {
sleep 2
puts 'thread_1'
}.join

puts 'main_thread'
```

This is the output I get:

```
thread_1
main_thread
```

This may seem logically to many but it doesn't to me.
I was expecting:

```
main_thread
thread_1
```

why? Because this is how I see things

```
main_thread : ----------(starts thread_1)-(prints 'main_thread')--Done!

thread_1    :                           \-(sleeps 2 secs)----------(prints 'thread_1')--Done!
```

But this is not happening. If I remove the .join part then 'thread_1' does not even show up.
From my understanding .join hangs up (pauses the main thread). Why? Isn't that against concurrency? Help clarifying my mind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread#join` waits for subthreads to complete before continuing, so the expected result is indeed what you're seeing.

If you move the join statement to the very end of your file, and then follow it with:

```
puts 'main_thread joined!'
```

You'll see:

```
main_thread
thread_1
main_thread joined!
```

Comment: Is that a good approach? Having join's position to decide this? What if I have to debug a 10k lines project, what will happen if I had to debug similar situations?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "good" approach. It depends on what you're doing. Re 10k line projects, be wary that debugging multi-threaded and concurrency-related issues code can be *very* hard; make sure you understand what you're doing before diving into threads.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby `Thread#join` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-join) makes the calling thread block until the target thread has completed, allowing you to "checkpoint" multiple threads.

Think of it this way, when you start a thread you go from one line of execution to two, and when you join a thread you go from two lines of execution to one.

```
Thread#start             Thread#join
------+---->     ...     ------O--->
      \---->     ...     ------/
```

It may seem odd but it is a common situation.  For example, suppose you have a thread doing work in the background and another thread can't proceed until that work is done; in this case "join" is a simple way to have the threads coordinate their activity.